# What's causing this sqldf error -- need to group by Customer_ID?

Tags: r, sqldf

I currently have a dataframe in R called `DDS_LS`. Currently each line is by transaction but I need the transactions aggregated by the Customer_ID.

```
sqldf("SELECT Customer_ID, count(distinct Lifestyle), count(distinct Price_Point),
         cumsum(Delivered_Sales), cumsum(QTY_sold)
        FROM DDS_LS GROUP BY Customer_ID")
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  external pointer is not valid
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the behavior (if not the root cause) by encouraging `sqldf` to persist the SQLite connection and manually closing it. That is, `library(sqldf); sqldf(); getOption("sqldf.connection");` shows a connection as active. If I close it with `dbDisconnect(getOption("sqldf.connection"))` and try a call to `sqldf`, it fails. This is the only way I can reproduce that error using `sqldf`, but it also seems unlikely that you would unwittingly do that. A reproducible example (from a fresh R instance) is very important here.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `cumsum`, which doesn't exist in `sqldf`. You can see the list of supported aggregating functions here: https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

If you want to get the cumulative sum, I recommend moving your code to `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
DDS_LS %>%
  group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
  summarise(count(distinct(Lifestyle)),
            count(distinct(Price_Point)),
            cumsum(Delivered_Sales),
            cumsum(QTY_sold))
```

Comment: The error provided doesn't match this answer. If it were just this, the error would read `no such function: cumsum` (I just checked). Instead it says `external pointer is not valid`, indicating something else entirely.

Comment: I also had trouble reproducing the exact error with some demo datasets, but I decided that the invalid call to `cumsum` meant the code was doomed no matter what so I suggested an alternative.